# Can we change target function for a running process in python multiprocess enviornment

Tags: python, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I am currently working on python multi processes and I have created multiple processes with some target function worker1 with different inputs and I want to reuse these processes after current work provided in target = worker1 is finished.

More specifically I want to change target function of running process now with a new target function worker2 with corresponding input. But I am not seeing an elegant way to do this with same process set.

Solutions what I can think of now are:

1) One solution could be terminate these process and create new process set with new target but that will create process creation overhead.

2) Use work queue and pass parameters but in this case the target function need to know about both work1 and work2 from start.

3) Worker pool but worker1 and worker2 are not same work so I want to keep them separate. 
Dummy code would be as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def worker1(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'Worker1:', num
    return

def worker2(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    print 'worker2:', num
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        print "start job i"
        p = mp.Process(target=worker1, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        p.join()

    for i in range(5):
        print "start job i"
        #map process p with new target worker2
        jobs[i].someFunc(target=worker2, args=(i,))
        jobs[i].join()


    for i in range(5):
        print len(jobs), i
        p = jobs[i]
        p.terminate()
        print 'TERMINATED:', p, p.is_alive()
        p.join()
```

Comment: got the answer? i want to change target arg too coz process Pool is a crab with result FIFO